# Socket.io event that waits for both players to have chosen answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am busy learning socket.io and trying to figure out how to make a bit of JS only fire off once both users have clicked their answers.

The code in question I am wanting to fire off is:

```
// Random number function    
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

// Check if correct + send to server
function correctAnswer() {
    var correct = true;
    socket.emit('playerCorrect', {answer: correct});
    console.log(correct);
    buttonRemover();

}
// Check if wrong + send to server
function incorrectAnswer () {
    var wrong   = false;
    socket.emit('playerWrong', {answer: wrong});
    buttonRemover();
}

socket.on ('updatePlayer', function (data) {
    if (data.answer === true) {
        console.log ('Player got it right! ' + data.answer);
    }else if (data.answer === false) {
        console.log ('Player got it wrong! ' + data.answer);
    }

});
```

What those functions are sending data to the server to let the server know if the answer was correct or not.

```
socket.on('playerCorrect', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('updatePlayer', data);
    dataRequest();
});    

socket.on('playerWrong', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('updatePlayer', data);
    dataRequest();
});
```

However I am only wanting this stuff to happen when both clients have clicked an option. Is there a way to track this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single set of users, it would suffice to do:

```
// Global variables for maintaining game states
// TODO: Clear this when a new game is started
var nrecieved = 0;
var responses = {}; // Socket id to response


function finish(/* todo: maybe also pass in a game_id or one of the user ids to know which game is being played */){
   // Loop through users in game and send them their responses
   for(var id in responses){
        if(responses.hasOwnProperty(id)){
             // Send the response
             io.to(id).emit('updatePlayer', responses[id]);
        }
   }
}

socket.on('playerCorrect', function (data) {
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    nrecieved++;

    if(nrecieved == 2){
        finish();
        dataRequest();
    }
});    

socket.on('playerWrong', function (data) {
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    nrecieved++;

    // Only respond if both responses received
    if(nrecieved == 2){
       finish();
       dataRequest();
    }
});
```

`socket.id` is a unique identifier assigned to each socket which may be useful. For multi-game performance, you will probably need to have more logic to maintain a list of which sockets/players belong to which games and then use that to direct messages to the correct pairs of users.

Comment: I would imagine this is all handled server side? :)

Comment: Yes, it can all be done on the server as long as you keep track of which games are being played with which users. It may help for the clients to pass  back which users they are playing with (maybe their ids or names) or something else to help the server know who is involved, but it is not necessary

Comment: I have a socket that allows them to enter usernames etc. I just wasnt tracking their unique id's. How would one go about creating multiple instances of a game, or creating different lobbies?

Comment: I also noticed that this works fine. But when the second player answers it doesnt log back their answer? :)

Comment: Lobbies are fairly easy: you can just say ask them for a lobby name and whenever you send a request to the server, include the current lobby name and on the server, you may have some variable `lobbies`, whose keys are `lobbies[name] = {some data for this lobby/game}`. This way when the server gets a request, it can use 'lobbie[name]' as a context. Similarly for pairing user's a client may send the id/name of the opponent

Comment: Make sure that the global variables are defined outside of `io.on('connection', ...)` so that they are shared between sockets

Comment: I see i see. Your above code works well. it just doesnt seem to be getting to the datarequest() function. Or console logging the 2nd players choice on client side. Unless it would only do that if I am in the developer tools of both?

Comment: Possibly, not that in my code, `datarequest` is only called once. You'd need to adapt `datarequest` to work like `finish` and handle all participants simultaneously

Comment: This would indeed seem to be the case. As its logging each side their answers. Would you mind taking a look at my pastebin to get your opinion on the whole app structure?

Comment: Overall looks fine. I'd try to separate out logic into more files/functions and keep it organized.

Comment: Yea I have been struggling to organize everything. Because for some reason I can put my stuff into different files. Havent been able to understand it. I will now try figure out how to call datarequest with both of those events.